# What are some common reasons mysql stops responding?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have to admin a mysql server, and was hoping people could give a few of the top reasons a mysql server might stop responding?

Vague question I know, but I'm looking to read up on preventative measures as a learning experience before I get some problems of my own.

What are common reasons a mysql server may crash? techniques to debug issues, etc.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with everything that ErikA said - those are very much frequent reasons that MySQL will crash - I have to disagree that any of those are the most likely reason that a MySQL server might stop *responding*.  Rather than MySQL crashing, in my experience it is far more likely that you will encounter database contention which will cause everything to get locked up behind one long-running query.  This is especially likely when you are making long-length and/or complex reads on the same tables as are being written to.

MyISAM, the default storage engine, is especially vulnerable to this as it uses table-level locking instead of row-level locking that InnoDB uses.  It's theoretically possible to have row-level contention, but it's far, far less likely to have lock problems when running InnoDB than MyISAM.  I'd read up on [table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html) if I were you.  I think that's much more likely.

I'd also add 'swapping' to the list of ErikA's results, though that is technically just a reason for very high I/O contention.